# "Switch User" screen highlight color barely visible

Tags: macos, catalina

I'm using the latest MacOS (Catalina) and when using the left and right keys to change which user is selected, it's barely visible which one is "highlighted".

There doesn't seem to be a simple way to change the background, so is there a way to change the selection color? Or perhaps some other solution?

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of where exactly you're having this issue?

Comment: @Allan Lock your screen and then click "Switch User".

Comment: It's easy to tell on mine so a *screenshot* showing us your *actual* conditions probably would be helpful.